# Consulta com subquery

Tags: sql

[image: tabelas do banco de dados]

Preciso responder a essa pergunta:
4) buscar o nome e endereço dos clientes que locaram todos os filmes da locadora.

Não tenho como testar a query, mas séria algo como isso?

```
SELECT C.nome, C.endereço from CLIENTES C
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM filmes F
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * from locaçoes L
    where F.id = L.filme and C.id = L.cliente
  )
)
```

Comment: A pergunta não está muito clara: você quer listar os dados dos clientes que já locaram absolutamente TODOS os filmes da locadora, ou seja, que não falte nenhum filme para ser alugado? Se for o caso a query teria que ser bem diferente disso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para listar os clientes que já alugaram absolutamente todos os filmes do catálogo da locadora, pode-se usar (dentre outras) a seguinte query:

```
SELECT C.nome, C.endereço FROM CLIENTES C
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Filme) FROM Locações WHERE cliente = C.id) 
      = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Filmes)
```

O que essa query faz é contar a quantidade de locações, sem considerar filmes alugados mais de uma vez (`COUNT(DISTINCT Filme)`), e listar apenas os que essa contagem seja igual a quantidade total de filmes da locadora.

Comment: Eu tinha tinha tentado assim, porém esqueci do distinct no count, caso o o mesmo cliente tenha alugado o filme 2 vezes ou mais, grato pela solução.